# javascript changelink function for 2 select

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to change the link at a button through a select, now i want to add an other select with an other button but i can only do that by adding the same function twice and change the name of one.
Any hint?

```
changelink(s) {
    if(s.options[0].selected){
        document.getElementById('yahoo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('google').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("wsj").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    if(s.options[1].selected){
        document.getElementById('yahoo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('google').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('wsj').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    if(s.options[2].selected){
        document.getElementById('yahoo').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('google').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('wsj').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? And what do you want the second button to link to? The same as the first?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30177800/test.html all the code is here i didn't know how to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, [**this should do it**](http://jsfiddle.net/XSeSZ/). I just changed the IDs to classes and added a parameter to the `changelink` function to make determining which `select` was used and which `a`s to affect

```
/* HTML */
<select onchange="changelink(this, 0)">
    <option value="0">3 mesi</option>
    <option value="1">6 mesi</option>
    <option value="2">9 mesi</option>
</select>
<a class="google" href="http://www.google.com">a</a>
<a class="yahoo" href="http://www.yahoo.com">b</a>
<a class="wsj" href="http://www.wsj.com">c</a>
<select onchange="changelink(this, 1)">
    <option value="0">3 mesi</option>
    <option value="1">6 mesi</option>
    <option value="2">9 mesi</option>
</select>
<a class="google" href="http://www.google.com">a</a>
<a class="yahoo" href="http://www.yahoo.com">b</a>
<a class="wsj" href="http://www.wsj.com">c</a>

/* Javascript */
function changelink(s, i) {
    if(s.options[0].selected){
        document.getElementsByClassName('yahoo')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName('google')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName("wsj")[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    if(s.options[1].selected){
        document.getElementsByClassName('yahoo')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName('google')[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementsByClassName('wsj')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    if(s.options[2].selected){
        document.getElementsByClassName('yahoo')[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementsByClassName('google')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName('wsj')[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Next time you should include some of your HTML or what you have so far as well so we can get a better idea how you want it to work

Comment: On a side note, you may want to use `display:none` over `visibility:hidden` because it will remove the spacing of the links when they are not visible